# How to transform Web.Config file 'Properly' with VSTS?

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, web.config-transform

I am working on DevOps with VSTS. I have the two web projects like **webproject1** and **webproject2** with Web.config files for each one. But those web projects of Web.config files consists of same keys with different values.

Example:
WebProjects1 contains the Web.config file with these key values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Server=XXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Database=XXXX;Connect Timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=200;Application Name=XXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

WebProjects2 contains the Web.config file with these key values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Server=XXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Database=XXXX;Connect Timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=200;Application Name=XXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

For those projects, I created the release definition in VSTS using **IIS Web App Manag**e and **IIS Web App Deploy Deployment** tasks. I want to replaces the key values with client key values in both Web.config files. But the two Web.config files having same keys. So, I am not unable to replace the keys with client values in two Web.config files using **XML variable substitution** option under IIS web App Deploy VSTS release task using **Variables** tab.

I followed this [link](https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/DevOps/TransformWebConfigFileWithVSTSWithoutTokenizationOrParametersXml) to transform Web.Config file 'Properly' with VSTS, but this document contains to replace keys with client values in single web.config file. But it doesn’t contains the explanation about if multiple web.config files having same keys in multiple projects.

I know to achieve the above problem using multi-configuration architecture like creating the Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config files for each web proejct in VS2015. But I don’t want this process.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Since you select Bitbucket repo as artifacts for VSTS release, how does the packages for the two web applications stored in your bitbucket repo? Two separate .zip files for the packages?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, drop contains individual folders of each web application, but not an .zip files.

Answer (score 3):

By default, MSBuild will "helpfully" parameterize your connection strings.  These would show up in root directory of your build artifact in the SetParameters.xml file.  This process conflicts when you try to use variables to set connectionstrings, as you are trying to do.

I would suggest turning off Auto Parameterization in your builds, and see if your connectionstrings are now replaced with your variable values.  You should be able to name a variable "DBConnectionString", bind it to an environment, and this process flow smoothly.

[image: Turn off Auto Parameterization]

Comment: Thanks @raterus, Right now I don't have to build the application in VSTS. But the build process takes place in some other third party tool like Bit Bucket. So, right now I used the drop from bit bucket if any changes are doing in release definition only not in build definition.

Comment: @pradeep, My answer isn't directly tied to Builds under VSTS, any build server may suffer from this issue.  I'd still check your "drop" artifact, and any SetParameters that may be interfering with what you are trying to accomplish in VSTS.  Also, set System.debug=true in your release variables, this will show some additional logging and you can track the logs when the variables are replaced.